# New to PyTorch, having trouble making predictions once data is loaded using Data Loader

Tags: pytorch, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm completely new to PyTorch (have previously used tensor flow) and I'm stuck on something I'm working on. I've been tasked with using a pretrained model to extract the features from application documents and then compute similarity scores to identify duplicates. I have all of the pdf's converted to .jpg's, and I've loaded the pretrained model and modified the last layer to extract features. The folder structure is like this:

```
root
|- Application 1
|   |- image 1
|   |- image 2...
|- Application 2
|   |- image 1
|   |- image 2...
```

What I'm trying to do is extract features from the images in every sub-directory and calculate the euclidean distance between them and output a similarity matrix. Where I'm having an issue, and this may seem really basic, is actually making the predictions once the data is loaded. Below is the code I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def get_pretrained_model_notop(model_name): #pull the model and change last layer
    pretrained_model = model_name(pretrained=True) #downloads pretrained model weights
    for param in pretrained_model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False #freezes layers
    pretrained_model = nn.Sequential(*list(pretrained_model.children())[:-1]) #drops final layer, because we aren't classifying 1000 imagenet classes
    pretrained_model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten() #adds flatten layer at end of model
                            )
    if torch.cuda.is_available(): #uses GPU if available
        pretrained_model = pretrained_model.cuda()
    return pretrained_model

def get_similarity(pretrained_model,train_imgs):   #function to extract features from the model and compute similarity scores
    bottleneck_feature_example = pretrained_model(train_imgs)
    similarity = euclidean_distances(bottleneck_feature_example)
    similarity=similarity/similarity.max()
    similarity_df = pd.DataFrame(similarity)
    similarity_df=1-similarity_df
    return np.round(similarity_df,4)

transforms =           transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

img_dir='path'
images = datasets.ImageFolder(img_dir,transform=transforms)  
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(images,
            batch_size=32,
            shuffle=True,
            num_workers=4)

model_list=[models.densenet201]
model_name=['densenet201']
pretrained_model=[get_pretrained_model_notop(selected_model) for selected_model in model_list]
for data in data_loader:
    pred=[get_similarity(pretrained,data) for pretrained in pretrained_model]
    pred_label_ensemble=sum(pred) / len(pred)   
    pred_label_ensemble.columns=page_numbers
    prob_output_folder = unzipped.replace('MF_loan_document', 'MF_loan_document_results')
    pred_label_ensemble.to_csv(prob_output_folder+'/'+'results.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the problem, but I would assume that it is because you're expecting `images` but passing `data` to the `get_similarity`. So, you'd need to change:

```
pred=[get_similarity(pretrained,data) for pretrained in pretrained_model]
```

to:

```
pred = [get_similarity(pretrained, data[0]) for pretrained in pretrained_model]
```

because `data` is a tuple with `(images, labels)`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting features out of pytorch model you need to register a forward hook.
This way you will not not need to modify the model itself.
Print the model and choose the layer you want -

```
model.chosen_layer.register_forward_hook(print_intermediate)
```

Every time there is a forward the function print_intermediate is called
The signature for print_intermediate is

`def print_intermediate(self, in_val):
    print (in_val)`

Instead of printing you can use a global list or some data structure to store the activations and calculate euclidean distance.